# How to push a local notification When a change happens in input data?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I fetch some data from a url and display data on a tableview. I need to create a local notification and inform(allert) user about the change when a new data is added to data source. How can i create such a notification( it must work even in bacground too)? Any idea-tutorial recommendation will be appropriate. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can create local notifications using UILocalNotification. You can either schedule it or present it. Look into Application.h for more info about it.

You can also plainly use notification center to handle such changes.

Some useful link:

```
http://blog.corywiles.com/uilocalnotification-example-project-using-ios
```